# insert json into db

Tags: 8, database

I'm trying to store some JSON data as string into database, but db_query change my JSON {} to table prefix.

So I have wrong JSON in DB as result.

How can I prevent such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using [db_query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7) for inserts (the docs specifically say you shouldn't) but that's not actually the source of this problem.

You should use [db_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_insert/7), and your data needs to be sent to the DB as a string.

```
// Mock json data -- notice it's stored as a string
$json_data = '[{
  "first_name": "Ralph",
  "last_name": "Wallace",
  "email": "test@example.com",
}]';

db_insert('my_table')
 ->fields(array(
  'fieldcontainingjson' => $json_data,
 ))->execute();
```

**Update in light of your comment stating that you can't use db_insert:**

First, you should consider if [db_merge()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_merge/7) will work for you.  But we won't argue that point and will just try to get this to work with db_query.

Make sure you're using placeholders correctly with db_query().  This should work:

```
$json_data = '[{
 "first_name": "Ralph",
 "last_name": "Wallace",
 "email": "test@example.com",
}]';

db_query('INSERT INTO {my_table} (fieldcontainingjson) VALUES (:json)', array(':json' => $json_data));
```

In the future it's considered best practices to share your code that's not working for you.

Comment: I cant use db_insert. Query uses structures that is unsupported by ORM. Like "INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"

Comment: @Braggae Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, after I started to use placeholders it work correctly.